# calculate elements occurrence in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of elements:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'c']
```

I want to produce a list with the elements occurrence, so for each element it counts how many times it appeared until this point:

Such that I will get:

```
elements_occurence: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

I tried:

```
occurrences = {}
for i in l:
    if i in occurrences:
        occurrences[i] += 1
    else:
        occurrences[i] = 1
```

But it gives me this result instead:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently just checking the ***end result*** of the dict. But if you *"save"* the intermediate values while iterating, you will get your result:

```py
occurrences = {}
elements_occurence = []
for i in l:
    if i in occurrences:
        occurrences[i] += 1
    else:
        occurrences[i] = 1
    elements_occurence.append(occurrences[i])
print(elements_occurence)
print(occurrences)
```

Gives:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2}
```

---

A few ways to improve your counting (in ascending order of being *"pythonic"*):

1. Use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

   ```
   for i in l:
       occurrences[i] = occurrences.setdefault(i, 0) + 1
   ```
2. Use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

   ```
   for i in l:
       occurrences[i] = occurrences.get(i, 0) + 1
   ```
3. Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict

   occurrences = defaultdict(int)
   for i in l:
       occurrences[i] += 1
   ```

Comment: What if i want to start counting the elements from 0 so that o get as a result: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1] ?

Comment: Use `get(i, -1)` or the `defaultdict` but put the `print` first...